# Criar uma Matriz Dinâmica usando AngularJS

Tags: javascript, array, angularjs, div, table

Preciso criar uma Matriz Dinâmica onde o usuário insere o tamanho dela.

Essa Matriz precisar ser usando `Div` e não `Table` do HTML, e o conteúdo a ser mostrado dentro da Matriz é em imagens e precisa ser navegável utilizando tanto o o Mouse quanto as Teclas direcionais.

Abaixo o Código e o que eu consegui fazer no Plunker.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.name = 'World';
   $scope.matriz =[];

   $scope.linha;
   $scope.coluna;

   $scope.getNumber = function(num) {
      return new Array (Number(num));   
   }
});
```

### HTML

```
<p>Linha</p>
        <input type="text" ng-model="linha" placeholder="Digite o tamanho..."> 
        <p>Coluna</p>
        <input type="text" ng-model="coluna"  placeholder="Digite o tamanho..." >
        <p></p>
        <table border="1" style="background-color:FFFFCC;border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid FFCC00;color:000000;width:100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
          <tr data-ng-repeat="i in getNumber(linha)">
           <td data-ng-repeat="i in getNumber(coluna)"> <input placeholder="Digite os dados..."> </td>
         </tr>
       </table>
```

Plunker do Projeto: http://embed.plnkr.co/75FnXMIsx4jBmBR7BCSn/

O que eu preciso é algo neste estilo: http://jsfiddle.net/BNrBX/

Mas implementando tambem a funcionalidade de escolher o tamanho da Matriz inserindo o valor das Linhas e Colunas